# OpenXML - replace a string by a table

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, openxml-powertools

I want to replace a string by a table, I can't make it work.

Here is the code for replacing a string:

```
var newDoc = new FileInfo(OpenXml_docx);
File.Copy(sourceDoc.FullName, newDoc.FullName);
using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newDoc.FullName, true)) {
    XDocument xDoc = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
    IEnumerable<XElement> content = xDoc.Descendants(W.p);
    int count = OpenXmlRegex.Replace(content, findeDas, "#BlaBla", null);
    Console.WriteLine("Example #1 Count: {0}", count); 
    wDoc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
}
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your regex? (`findeDas` value).

Also you could probably try to use other override of Replace:

```
var newDoc = new FileInfo(OpenXml_docx);
File.Copy(sourceDoc.FullName, newDoc.FullName);
using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newDoc.FullName, true)) {
    XDocument xDoc = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
    IEnumerable<XElement> content = xDoc.Descendants(W.p);
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var e in content) {  
        count += OpenXmlRegex.Replace(e, findeDas, "#BlaBla", null);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Example #1 Count: {0}", count); 
    wDoc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
}
```

Comment: This is the regular expression(`@"\${(.*?)}";`) and it will be applied to all placeholders of that kind  `${somePlaceholderInWord}`.

Comment: Can you show example of your Word? as it works for me on simple document with content like `1 ${aaa} ewq`. Doo you have linebreaks inside of {}?

Comment: no line breaks inside of `{}`, but they are at different places inside a table, paragraph ...